# Java Algorithm Bug

Tags: java, algorithm

This method should return smallest similar value that found in two array. It works with this input:

```
int[] C={1,3,2,1};
int[] D={4,2,5,3,2};

public static  int getSmallestSimilar(int[] C, int[] D) {
        int n = A.length;
        int m = B.length;
        Arrays.sort(A);
        Arrays.sort(B);
        int i = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            System.out.println( B[i] +"::"+ A[k] );
            System.out.println( i +"::"+ k );
            if (i < m - 1 && B[i] < A[k])
                i += 1;
            if (A[k] == B[i])
                return A[k];
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work with this input:

```
 int[] A={15,9}  and int[] B={6,9,3};
```

i try to solve problem but i can't , please help

Comment: it's not depend on array size it may be with difference size , ? how i can solve ?

Comment: An additional issue, in the same line -- you advance the index for B, but only once. You might (as in this case) advance to another B value that's also less than the A value. So ... consider whether you want an `if` statement that executes at most once, or another type of statement that can execute more than once.

Comment: @SalahBenAtwa - it does depend on array size. the line part: "if I < m -1 means that you are < B.size()

Comment: @SalahBenAtwa it also means that you are < B.size()-1

Answer (score 0):

B was 2 indices ahead. the if only incremented once.
Change your loop to

```
           for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                // A[k] = 9, catch up B[i] until b is greater than or equal.
                while (i < m - 1 && B[i] < A[k])
                    i += 1;
                if (A[k] == B[i])
                    return A[k];
       }
```

Comment: Wait a minute. I think you only want to go through once. I'll change it.

Comment: @SalahBenAtwa , Did this correct your problem? If so, can you please mark it as solved?

Answer (score 0):

`k` should be incremented only if `B[i]>A[k]`

This loop should work:

```
    int i = 0,k = 0;
    for (;;) {
        if(i >= m || k >= n)
            return -1;    //or anything which implies no match found
        System.out.println( B[i] + "::" + A[k] );
        System.out.println( i + "::" + k );
        if (B[i] < A[k])
            i += 1;
        if (B[i] > A[k])
            k += 1;
        if (A[k] == B[i])
            return A[k];
    }
```